# Convert to string in python

Tags: python, opencv

i am working on my project where i i want to capture video frames from my webcam and send to remote client in python, i am using opencv to capture frames but i have to send it to remote client frame by frame without saving in server...
I am stuck here since a week pls help me 
should i have to conver it to string to send via sockets? if yes then how?
PLS help me my code is

```
import cv2
import socket
import base64

host = "localhost"
port = 6052

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(5)
print "server started...."
#if __name__ == "__main__":
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print "client connected..."
    capture = cv2.cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
    #cv2.cv.NamedWindow('image')
    frame = cv2.cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    #cv2.cv.ShowImage('image', frame)
    #succ, ig = cv2.cv.LoadImage(capture)
    with open(frame,"rb") as f:
        es = base64.b64encode(f.read())
        stri = str.decode('base64','strict')
        print "string is " + stri
    #with open(ig, "rb") as f:
    #   b = f.read(87029)
    #  print "data = " + b
   # c.send(b)


   #k = cv2.cv.WaitKey(10)

   #if k % 256 ==27 :
        #break

#cv2.DestroyWindow('image')
    s.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is the _problem_ with this code? What is it doing wrong?

Comment: problem is in line c.send(b), it says have to type error, i am not able to send the frames to client..

Comment: Well, _what is `b`?_ Paste the exception and traceback, and tell us what the type of `b` is. (If you don't know, just ask Python: `print(type(b))`. Also, tell us whether this is Python 2.x or 3.x. And give us code that actually runs if you want anyone to help you debug it; this code just gives a `NameError` on that `ig` variable.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the problems in the other answer—which you still have to fix—you have *another* problem.

```
frame = cv2.cv.QueryFrame(capture)
open(frame,"rb")
```

[`QueryFrame`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#IplImage*%20cvQueryFrame(CvCapture*%20capture)) returns an image object. [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) takes a filename or an integer file descriptor. An image object is quite obviously not a filename, so that `open` is going to raise an exception.

The only way you're going to get a filename that you can pass to `open` is if you have a file, e.g., by saving the frame to it. You claim that you had code that did that. Presumably in that code, you had code similar to this:

```
cv2.cv.imwrite(filename, image, params)
f = open(filename, 'rb')
```

I don't know what params you used; the `image` is presumably the image you read by capturing a frame.

The [`imencode`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode) function is similar to `imwrite`, except that it creates an image file in-memory, in a buffer, instead of writing it to disk. It takes the same parameters as `imwrite`, except with a file extension instead of a full filename (because it isn't going to save anything to disk, but it still needs to know what type of file—PNG, JPE, etc.).

So:

```
buf = cv2.cv.imencode(extension, image, params)
```

And now, `buf` is the bytes you can pass to `send`.

Comment: since i am new to python i don't know much, in simple i am trying to send is image captured from my webcam without saving it to client, for some time consider client as browser hope u can help me now.. –

Comment: @Learner: I have no idea what "for some time consider client as browser" means. A browser doesn't make raw socket calls, it makes HTTP requests. If you want to build a web server, you have to do that (or, better, use a framework that does it for you).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're trying to solve is here:

```
c.send(b)
```

If you read the docs for [`socket.send`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send):

> Send data to the socket. The socket must be connected to a remote socket. The optional *flags* argument has the same meaning as for `recv()` above. Returns the number of bytes sent. **Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data.** For further information on this concept, consult the [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto).

And in fact, sending a big hunk of data immediately upon opening a TCP socket is exactly the kind of situation where you'd expect it to send only part of the data.

You could read the linked HOWTO, which will explain how to deal with partially-sent buffers, but for your problem, since you're doing nothing but handling one client at a time with no concurrency, completing the request, and hanging up on it, the next function in the docs, [`sendall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall), does everything you want.

---

However, this isn't the only problem in your code. For example, the very next line does this:

```
s.close
```

Just referencing a function, without calling it with `()`, has no effect. Which turns out to be a good thing, because if this *had* an effect, it would be closing the *listener* socket, not the *client* socket. If the client waits for shutdown, it would wait forever; meanwhile, if a second client tried to connect, it would be rejected.

---

Also, if you wrote the client side yourself, I'm willing to bet you just used `b = s.recv(87029)`, which is going to have the same problem: it's not necessarily going to receive 87029 bytes, it'll receive anything *up to* that many bytes. You have to loop around `recv` adding to a buffer until you get enough. See [Sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) for more details.

Comment: i can send if the image is already is saved, but i can't send the captured frames without saving it..  help me with the code, thanx for ur help..  example code is appreciated...

Comment: @Learner: What have you tried to send the captured frames? Your code shows you calling [`QueryFrame`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv.QueryFrame) to get an image object. What code are you using to get the bytes out of it? If you don't show us that, and instead show us different code that opens a file, how can anyone debug it?

Comment: yup i've wrote client side also.. for the line b=s.recv(87029) i was sending already saved image in my pc, it is working fine for statically present data, but my problem is i don't want to save those frames, just capture and send to client how can i do it??

Comment: since i am new to python i don't know much, in simple i am trying to send is image captured from my webcam without saving it to client, for some time consider client as browser hope u can help me now..

Comment: @Learner: If you're only going to answer about a third of the questions that you're asked, and aren't going to show us the actual code that you're having a problem with, how can anyone possibly help you?

Comment: thats all my complete code my friend.. i don't know it should just capture image from webcam and send to client via sockets..

Comment: @Learner: That can't possibly be your complete code, because that code raises `NameError: name 'ig' is not defined`.

Comment: ok i will edit my question and post my whole code in which i am just doing alterations to run it...

Answer (score 0):

- please, *never, ever* try to convert an image to a string, it's a total waste.
- yes, you will have to encode the image fom the webcam, but *not* to base64 (instead,you will need an image, that your client can read, like a png in memory)
- do not use the deprecated cv2.cv api, it will be gone soon (opencv 3.0)
- stick to a well known *protocol*, like MJPEG

---

```
import cv2
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer
import time

capture=None

class CamHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print self.path
        if self.path.endswith('.mjpg'):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary')
            self.end_headers()
            while True:
                try:
                    rc,img = capture.read()
                    if not rc:
                        continue
                    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    r, buf = cv2.imencode(".jpg",imgRGB)
                    self.wfile.write("--jpgboundary\r\n")
                    self.send_header('Content-type','image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-length',str(len(buf)))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(bytearray(buf))
                    self.wfile.write('\r\n')
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
            return
        if self.path.endswith('.html') or self.path=="/":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('<html><head></head><body>')
            self.wfile.write('<img src="http://127.0.0.1:9090/cam.mjpg"/>')
            self.wfile.write('</body></html>')
            return

def main():
    global capture
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320); 
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('',9090),CamHandler)
        print "server started"
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        capture.release()
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```